# anti-forgery key is now required for methods that does not have property ValidateAntiForgeryToken

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I installed the AntiForgery protection for some methods, and I select them by specifying

> [ValidateInput(false), ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

but now, when i call other methods in different controllers AntiForgery key is required:

> A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid

Answer (score 0):

If any not existing in controller Method found, and the default route to the this controller has specified `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute exception

> A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid

will always appear.

The solution is: Make sure that the method you are calling exist in controller an it does not have the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute